# How to trigger bootstrap-vue dropdown from outside element?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to open bootstrap-vue dropdown from a outside button. For instance:

```
 <b-dropdown>
    <template #button-content>
      Custom <strong>Content</strong> with <em>HTML</em> via Slot
    </template>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">An item</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">Another item</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>

<b-button @click="openDropdown">Open Dropdown</b-button> 

<script>
methods: {
 openDropdown(){
   // do something
 }
}
</script>
```

I see a similar discussion [here](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/pull/1012). But none of them are working. Any update of it or any other method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PR you linked added `show` and `hide` methods which can be accessed by adding a `ref` to the `<b-dropdown>`, and then referencing this ref in your method.

```html
<b-dropdown ref="myDropdown"></b-dropdown>
```

```js
openDropdown() {
  this.$refs.myDropdown.show();
}
```

##### Working Example

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  methods: {
    openDropdown() {
      this.$refs.myDropdown?.show();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="p-4">
  <b-dropdown ref="myDropdown">
    <template #button-content>
      Custom <strong>Content</strong> with <em>HTML</em> via Slot
    </template>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">An item</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#">Another item</b-dropdown-item>
  </b-dropdown>

  <b-button @click="openDropdown">Open Dropdown</b-button>
</div>
```

Comment: Works ! what's the difference between `this.$refs.myDropdown?.show();` & `this.$refs.myDropdown.show()` ?

Comment: The `?.` is [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), in-case the ref is undefined/null.